# Several Layers of If Statements with String

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,2,1,5,'Stay',2],[4,5,6,10,'Leave',10],
                   [10,20,30,40,'Stay',11],[12,2,3,3,'Leave',15],
                   [31,23,31,45,'Stay',25],[12,21,17,6,'Stay',15],
                   [15,17,18,12,'Leave',10],[3,2,1,5,'Stay',3],
                   [12,2,3,3,'Leave',12]], columns = ['A','B','C','D','Status','E'])


    A   B   C   D Status   E
0   3   2   1   5   Stay   2
1   4   5   6  10  Leave  10
2  10  20  30  40   Stay  11
3  12   2   3   3  Leave  15
4  31  23  31  45   Stay  25
5  12  21  17   6   Stay  15
6  15  17  18  12  Leave  10
7   3   2   1   5   Stay   3
8  12   2   3   3  Leave  12
```

I want to run a condition where if Status is Stay and if column E is smaller than column A, then: change the data where data in column D is replaced with data column C, data in column C is replaced with data from column B and data in column B is replaced with data from column A and data in column A is replaced with data from column E.
If Status is Leave and if column E is larger than column A, then: change the data where data in column D is replaced with data column C, data in column C is replaced with data from column B and data in column B is replaced with data from column A and data in column A is replaced with data from column E.

So the result is:

```
    A   B   C   D Status   E
0   2   3   2   1   Stay   2
1  10   4   5   6  Leave  10
2  10  20  30  40   Stay  11
3  15  12   2   3  Leave  15
4  25  31  23  31   Stay  25
5  12  21  17   6   Stay  15
6  15  17  18  12  Leave  10
7   3   2   1   5   Stay   3
8  12   2   3   3  Leave  12
```

My attempt:

```
if df['Status'] == 'Stay':
    if df['E'] < df['A']:
        df['D'] = df['C']
        df['C'] = df['B']
        df['B'] = df['A']
        df['A'] = df['E']
elif df['Status'] == 'Leave':
        if df['E'] > df['A']:
        df['D'] = df['C']
        df['C'] = df['B']
        df['B'] = df['A']
        df['A'] = df['E']
```

This runs into several problems including problem with string. Your help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want boolean indexing:

```
s1 = df.Status.eq('Stay') & df['E'].lt(df['A'])
s2 = df.Status.eq('Leave') & df['E'].gt(df['A'])
s = s1 | s2
df.loc[s, ['A','B','C','D']] = df.loc[s, ['E','A','B','C']].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D Status   E
0   2   3   2   1   Stay   2
1  10   4   5   6  Leave  10
2  10  20  30  40   Stay  11
3  15  12   2   3  Leave  15
4  25  31  23  31   Stay  25
5  12  21  17   6   Stay  15
6  15  17  18  12  Leave  10
7   3   2   1   5   Stay   3
8  12   2   3   3  Leave  12
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.roll` with `.loc`:

```
shift = np.roll(df.select_dtypes(exclude='object'),1,axis=1)[:, :-1]

m1 = df['Status'].eq('Stay') & (df['E'] < df['A'])
m2 = df['Status'].eq('Leave') & (df['E'] > df['A'])

df.loc[m1|m2, ['A','B','C','D']] = shift[m1|m2]

    A   B   C   D Status   E
0   2   3   2   1   Stay   2
1  10   4   5   6  Leave  10
2  10  20  30  40   Stay  11
3  15  12   2   3  Leave  15
4  25  31  23  31   Stay  25
5  12  21  17   6   Stay  15
6  15  17  18  12  Leave  10
7   3   2   1   5   Stay   3
8  12   2   3   3  Leave  12
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
#Status like index to use shift
new_df=df.set_index('Status')
#DataFrame to replace
df_modify=new_df.shift(axis=1,fill_value=df['E'])
#Creating boolean mask
under_mask=(df.Status.eq('Stay'))&(df.E<df.A)
over_mask=(df.Status.eq('Leave'))&(df.E>df.A)
#Using DataFrame.mask
new_df=new_df.mask(under_mask|over_mask,df_modify).reset_index()



print(new_df)
```

---

**Output**

```
  Status   A   B   C   D   E
0   Stay   2   3   2   1   5
1  Leave  10   4   5   6  10
2   Stay  10  20  30  40  11
3  Leave  15  12   2   3   3
4   Stay  25  31  23  31  45
5   Stay  12  21  17   6  15
6  Leave  15  17  18  12  10
7   Stay   3   2   1   5   3
8  Leave  12   2   3   3  12
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do this for each row of the data, but your code is written to try to do it at the top level.  Can you use a `for ... in` loop to iterate over the rows?

```
for row in df:
    if row['Status'] == 'Stay':
        ... etc ...
```

Comment: I wanted to use loop as well, but if the dataframe gets larger it will run slower. That's why I look for a vectorization solution. Thanks.